# How to autoresize UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

In my app is an infopage. The textllength could differ due to localization. Beside that has a 3.5" screen less real-estate than a 4" display. So what I try to achieve is that the UILabel "grows" inside a ScrollView and the Scrollview adapts to the screen.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Create a ScrollView and a label
UIScrollView *infoScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 55.0f, 300.0f, 400.0f)];

CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 800);
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];

NSString *labelText = NSLocalizedString (@"InfoText",@"");
[infoLabel setText:labelText];

// Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
[infoLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[infoLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1.0];
[infoLabel sizeToFit];
infoScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(infoScroll.contentSize.width, infoLabel.frame.size.height);
[infoScroll addSubview:infoLabel];

[self.view addSubview:infoScroll];

}
```

Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As stated I want the ScrollView adapt to the size of the screen. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You might want to look into autoresize masks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your function by below way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Create a ScrollView and a label
    UIScrollView *infoScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 55.0f, self.view.frame.size.width - 20.0, self.view.frame.size.height - 55)];
    infoScroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    infoLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;        

NSString *labelText = NSLocalizedString (@"InfoText",@"");
    [infoLabel setText:labelText];

    // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
    [infoLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [infoLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1.0];
    //[infoLabel sizeToFit];

    CGSize infoLabelSize = [infoLabel.text sizeWithFont:infoLabel.font
               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(infoScroll.frame.size.width, 5000)
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    infoLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height);
    infoScroll.contentSize = infoLabelSize;
    [infoScroll addSubview:infoLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:infoScroll];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. I made the changes but it does not work the proper way. On a 3.5" display it is OK but on a 4" display the scrollView is to short. Any suggestions?

Comment: GREAT!!! That did the trick. I only had to add a couple of blanc textlines to my localized text and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much. I hope that I gain as much knowledge as you have. Maybe it will comes with experience. I hope it will. Thank you very much.